# Access to the original query through SQLWarning

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I was wondering if there's a way to access the original SQL query from a SQLException/SQLWarning. I thought that that was unlikely, but the sentence `Warnings are silently chained to the object whose method caused it to be reported` in the API documentation brought me some hope.

And if it's not possible, what would be the best way around? Create a subclass from SQLWarning that holds the query information in the case of an exception? Or a class to call every time I want to make a SQL query and that takes care of the exception?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `SQLException` ( and therefor `SQLWarning`) does not contain the statement that was executed. There is no way around this. You will need to handle this yourself in some way. In theory a driver implementation could add this information, but this would be non-standard outside of the JDBC specification and API.

> Warnings are silently chained to the object whose method caused it to be reported

This means that the `SQLWarning` is added to the `java.sql.Statement` (or other JDBC object) a warning can be obtained using [`getWarnings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings%28%29) which returns a single `SQLWarning`, that has a chain of zero or more warnings.